# Error while transfer data from 2nd activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 Activity.
`FirstActivity` with 1 textView and 1 button, and
`MainActivity` with 4 checkBoxes, 1 textView and 1 button.
**First Activity is the first activity which app show to user.**

[Layouts of my activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e4li.png)

On the FirstActivity i want to check how many checboxes are checked in the textView.
On the MainActivity all working fine, we can select checkboxes and textView show how many is checked. Adittionaly, state of checkboxes and state of textView is save into SharedPreference.

Now i describe my problem, i dont know how to show currently numbers of checked boxes in 1st activity in my app after launch.
I tried to use `onActivityResult` but i think i do this wrong, and this my button2 with double intent must be also wrong.

What i should fix here and how ?

I paste here code of my 2 Activities:

**FirstActivity :**

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME = "abc";
private Button b1;
private TextView tv2;
private int number;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2) ;

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    number = preferences.getInt("NUMBER", 0);
    tv2.setText(""+number);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            int number = data.getExtras().getInt("number");
            tv2.setText(""+number);

            number = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("number");
            saveNumberToSharedPrefs(number);

        }
    }
}

private void saveNumberToSharedPrefs(int num){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); //Create and store this instance in onCreate method of activity, or use it like this.
    preferences.edit().putInt("NUMBER", num).apply(); // Use constant value for key
}
```

}

**MainActivity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private int numberOfTrue;
private TextView tv1;
private CheckBox cb1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CheckBox cb2,cb3,cb4;
    Button b2;

    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);

    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    cb1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    cb1.setChecked(getFromSP("cb1"));
    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb2);
    cb2.setChecked(getFromSP("cb2"));
    cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb3);
    cb3.setChecked(getFromSP("cb3"));
    cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb4);
    cb4.setChecked(getFromSP("cb4"));
    cb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    loadVariable();

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent output = new Intent();
        output.putExtra("number", numberOfTrue);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, output);
        finish();

        }
    });

}

private boolean getFromSP(String key){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}
private void saveInSp(String key,boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private void saveVariable(int numberOfTrue){

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("key2", numberOfTrue);
    editor.commit();

}

private void loadVariable(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int number = sharedPref.getInt("key2", 0);
    tv1.setText(""+number);
    numberOfTrue=number;

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    switch(buttonView.getId()){
        case R.id.cb1:
            saveInSp("cb1",isChecked);
            if (isChecked == true){
                numberOfTrue++;

            }
            else
            {
                numberOfTrue--;

            }
            break;
        case R.id.cb2:
            saveInSp("cb2",isChecked);
            if (isChecked == true){
                numberOfTrue++;

            }
            else
            {
                numberOfTrue--;

            }
            break;

        case R.id.cb3:
            saveInSp("cb3",isChecked);
            if (isChecked == true){
                numberOfTrue++;

            }
            else
            {
                numberOfTrue--;

            }
            break;

        case R.id.cb4:
            saveInSp("cb4",isChecked);
            if (isChecked == true){
                numberOfTrue++;

            }
            else
            {
                numberOfTrue--;

            }
            break;

    }

    saveVariable(numberOfTrue);
    loadVariable();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one if definitely wrong.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("number", numberOfTrue);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);

Intent output = new Intent();
output.putExtra("number", numberOfTrue);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, output);
finish();
```

You need to left only second part of code. Like this:

```
Intent output = new Intent();
output.putExtra("number", numberOfTrue);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, output);
finish();
```

And start your `MainActivity` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); // This change is important.
```

And then do this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

         number = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("number");

    }
}
```

This way you'll receive number from `MainActivity` when it'll be closed. But if you want to read this value on `FirstActivity` start (without going to `MainActivity`, you need to store checked number in shared preferences and then get value in `onCreate()` method of `FirstActivity`.
Write into `SharedPreferences` in `onActivityResult` to insure that only "saved" checks will be saved.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

         number = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("number");
         saveNumberToSharedPrefs(number);
    }
} 

private void saveNumberToSharedPrefs(int num){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); //Create and store this instance in onCreate method of activity, or use it like this.
    preferences.edit().putInt("NUMBER", num).apply(); // Use constant value for key
}
```

And then you can load your checked number in `onCreate` method of `FirstActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
number = preferences.getInt("NUMBER", 0);
}
```

### Update

Here you'r trying to get number from intent in `onActivityResult`. That's wrong, this way you'll always have number = 0 (default value). On activity result doesn't fill data into intent. All your data is in `data` variable passed in method.

```
number = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("number");
saveNumberToSharedPrefs(number);
```

You need to leave only this:

```
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) { //also you need to check if result is RESULT_OK
        number = data.getExtras().getInt("number");
        tv2.setText(""+number);
        saveNumberToSharedPrefs(number);
    }
```

Comment: finally i implemented this 1st part work, my application transfer good data from MainActivity to FirstActivity, but i try to "read this value on FirstActivity start (without going to MainActivity)" and no working, could you check my code ? i updated my question with currently code

Answer (score 1):

FirstActivity
Store values :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity
Fetching Values:

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
```

change on `FirstActivity.java`

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
```

add `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
                Log.d("TAG","------"+data.getExtras().getInt("number"));
                int number = data.getExtras().getInt("number");
                tv2.setText(""+number);
            }
        }
    }
```

change on `MainActivity.java`

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Log.d("TAG","------"+numberOfTrue);
                Intent output = new Intent();
            output.putExtra("number", numberOfTrue);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, output);
            finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @steve put Log in click of Button B2 and check the value of variable numberOfTrue    like Log.d("TAG","--------"+numberOfTrue );

Comment: when i checked 2 boxes, log show: "TAG: --------2" so its fine in my opinion

Comment: @steve no when clicking on button B2 that what shows in Logcat

Comment: Now i don't understand, after clicking on button B2, numberOfTrue have a good values, so what is wrong now ?

Comment: yes, i have this same in my b2 now, and in Android Monitor i see: "06-29 13:04:59.372 16785-16785/com.example.selection D/TAG: ------3" - when i have 3 checked boxes, when i have only 1 checked i see: "06-29 13:07:32.702 16785-16785/com.example.selection D/TAG: ------1"

Comment: @steve click on checkbox3 and click b2 button and check value is same

Comment: when is only checkbox3 clicked, i see TAG: ------1

Comment: click button b2 and check what is current value of numberOfTrue

Comment: ok i remove "onResume" method and is better, but now Only testView works when i go to MainActivity and back to FirstActivity ;/ i would to see numvers in testView after launch FirstActivity

Comment: @steve you have u put logic for this

Comment: The number in textView is only visible to the user, when he go to MainActivity and when he presses button "back"